# Conectar mysql a drupal 7

Tags: mysql, drupal7

tengo problemas al conectar MySQL a Drupal 7, resulta que tengo instalado MySQL en un servidor aparte con IP: 192.168.0.5 puerto 3306 con una base de datos de nombre drupal y un usuario de nombre drupal. 
Mi Drupal 7 esta instalado en una maquina con IP: 192.168.0.40, al momento de instalar y configurar la conexion a la base de datos me aparece el siguiente error:

> Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.5' (13).

estos son los datos que utilizo para la conexion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como solucionar ese error.

Comment: Saludos Felipe, bienvenido al sitio. Revisa este enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla :D Intenta conectarte desde MySQL Workbench u otro administrador de base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

La gama de problemas que puedes tener es muy amplia. Pero viendo el error para un tema de conectividad.

Empieza por lanzar un ping de una máquina a otra. Si es resultado es correcto, lanza un comando telnet al puerto 3306 de la máquina de base de datos.

Según el resultado que obtengas de estas pruebas deberás tomar unas u otras medidas.

Comment: se me olvido mencionar que , drupal esta instalado en rhel y mysql en windows

Comment: Los problemas de conectividad seguirían siendo los mismos, aunque si varía la solución. Los comandos que te comento puedes lanzarlos desde el rhel.

Comment: al parecer la comunicación no es bidireccional , ya que desde la maquina donde esta MySQL hago ping a la ip de drupal y me responde, pero desde la maquina de drupal hacia la maquina donde esta MySQL no hay respuesta.

Comment: Siendo una máquina Windows, revisar los firewall y desactívalos todos para realizar una prueba. De conectar de esta manera, puedes incluir una única regla para dejar paso a mysql.

Comment: he desactivado el firewall de windows y efectivamente se produce una comunicación bidireccional, pero aun aparece el error en drupal 7 :/

Comment: Si el comando telnet establece conexión, el problema radica en los credenciales o el nombre de la base de datos.